# Socket.IO works locally, but not exernally

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am new to Node.js and im trying to complete a simple chat application. 
But im stuck. I tried to google and used other solutions, but i cant find it working for some reason. If someone can help me out that will be great.

The error im getting is that it took too long to respond.

Here is my code.

Server side:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

//##### PUSH HTML FILE
app.get('/', function(req, res){
     res.sendFile(__dirname +'/index.html');
});

//##### START SERVER
http.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0', function(){
     console.log('started on port: 3000');
});

//##### USER CONNECTED
io.on('connection', function(socket){
     console.log('A User Connected');

//##### LOG MESSAGE
socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    console.log(msg);
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
});

//##### LOG USERNAME
socket.on('set username', function(username){
    console.log('NEW USER: ' + username + ' has been set!');
    io.emit('set username', username);
});

//#####USER DISCONNECTED
socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('A user disconnected');
    });
});
```

Client side:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io();

        //##### SET USERNAME
        $('#set_username').submit(function(){
            socket.emit('set username', $('#username').val());
            return false;
        });

        //##### SET MESSAGE
        $('#sendmsg').submit(function(){
        var msg = '['+$('#username').val()+'] ' + $('#m').val();

            socket.emit('chat message', msg);
            $('#m').val('');
            return false;
        });

        //SET MESSAGE
        socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
            $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
        });
    </script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you specifying the server to connect to in the client?

Comment: You are behind a NAT.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark here, I've a feeling port 3000 on your server is behind a firewall, or like @Turrican say's you might need to setup a NAT on your router..  The point been TCP/IP has no distinction between localhost (127.0.0.1), or any other IP.  And your listening on all interfaces 0.0.0.0, so it's not your node apps that's the problem.

Comment: @Turrican I am. I portforwarded the port. http://imgur.com/a/ht6vT

Comment: What error message you are getting?

Comment: Your Local IP is wrong... 192.158???? (This is a WAN IP) Typo here... normally a private IP is 192.168.x.x

Comment: @Turrican MYGOD I AM SO STUPID. Thanks so much. It works now. IT are the small mistakes

Comment: No problem :) Everybody makes mistakes.

Comment: Can you accept the answer from below? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the comments :

You are listening at port 3000 behind a NAT. If you want to connect from outside you need to config port forwarding in your router to your local server. You have a typo in your NAT rule.